# Excel 2016 list of options for connection to DB has suddenly reduced, (MySQL, PostgreSQL)

Tags: mysql, connection, database, microsoft-excel-2016, power-query

I work with open source dbs such as MySQL or PostgreSQL as a back-end data storage with my excel 2016.

I had the full list of connections to all different kinds of dbs but they are suddenly reduced to the following,

[image: Screen Capture]

Before that I had heaps more options..

I just don't know where it went wrong and how to bring them back.

Is re-installing Office 365 going to solve the problem? or are there any other possible fixes available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your Excel SKU/Edition is not Professional Plus, Office 365 ProPlus or Excel Standalone.  For Excel 2013+, they are the only Editions that include full Power Query functionality.

The best info on this topic seems to be this page on Ken Puls' forum:

http://www.excelguru.ca/forums/showthread.php?5745-Installing-Power-Query

Comment: Thanks alot, I have realised that I'm on the Business plan instead of the Pro or Pro Plus.

Comment: An alternative would be to download the free Power BI Desktop tool, and rebbuild or copy your Power Queries in a PBID file.  You could then complete your analysis in PBI.

Comment: If you need the data back in Excel, you could publish it to the PBI web service, navigate to the Dataset, choose Analyze in Excel. For more info: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-analyze-in-excel/

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, you seem to have lost the connectors. You can redownload the [MySQL connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=412152) and [Postgre connector](https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql/releases). They should both be compatible with 32- and 64-bit, so I wouldn't expect that to be the problem.